# Serve Single File Without Extension Asp Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, iis

In order to use a service named ManDriller I need to put a file with a specific name in my domain, the file name would be something like:

**mandrill._domainkey.mysite.com.br**

How could I serve this single file, without enabling eveything else?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look like a file name, but rather a [TXT Record](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/TXT_Record), which can be added at your DNS registrar. See [How to Add DNS Records for Sending Domains](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582267-About-SPF-and-DKIM#set-up-spf-and-dkim-for-your-sending-domains) for more information.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I was trying to add a file to the ftp.

Answer (score 0):

The default is that IIS serves anything with an extension directly. Therefore, all you have to do is place the file somewhere in your document root, and it will be available. Not sure what more you're looking for. MVC doesn't have to be involved at all, and honestly, probably shouldn't be.

Comment: The mvc does not serve this file. In any case, the guy bellow was right.